# Accessing value of df.write.partitionBy in file name and performing transformations while saving

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am doing something like

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("sourcefilename").format("orc").save("s3a://my/dir/path/output-data");
```

The above code does generate orc file name successfully with the partition directory however the naming is something like part-0000.

I need to change the partition by (sourcefilename) value while saving e.g. if source file name is ABC then the partition directory (which would be create while doing a write) should be 123, if DEF then 345 and so on.

How can we do the above requirements? I am using AWS S3 for reading and writing of files.

I am using Spark 2.x and Scala 2.11.

Comment: Nick, how r u feeling about the answers? Did u solve otherwise?

Comment: Yeah, the answers are there but not what I was looking for. Moreover, why the two downvotes, definitely not right and not motivating!

Comment: Well, the answer can be not what you want to hear of course. I dic not down vote and have been subjected to it. It is the nature of some here, that said, it is a very informative site.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this example show the DF Writer general

```
df.write.partitionBy("EVENT_NAME","dt","hour").save("/apps/hive/warehouse/db/sample")
```

format, then your approach should be to create an extra column xc that is set by a UDF or some def or val that sets the xc according to the name, e.g. ABC --> 123, etc. Then you partition by this xc col and accept that part-xxxxx is just how it works in Spark.

You could then rename the files via a script yourself subsequently.

Comment: Thanks, but I know that I could rename them later. I was wondering if there was a way to have the file name embedded while doing .save operation

Comment: No, you cannot get around part aspect upfront. Does not make sense. Answer is hence correct.

Answer (score 0):

The part-1234 style is how the work is partitioned: different tasks get their own partition of the split data source and saves it with the numbering to guarantee no other task generates output with the same name.

This is fundamental to getting the performance of parallel execution.